# How to print a list containing strings with a specific number of spaces between each string?

Tags: string, list, formatting, spaces

I'm working on making code that prints strings from a list, however I need to have it so that their are a specific number of spaces between each word. I'm also working with java.

Comment: Which language are you working in?

Comment: @jrtapsell java

Comment: You'll want to include an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like so:

```
for (String item : list) {
    System.out.print(item + "   ");
}
System.out.println();
```

assuming the number of spaces is low you can just add it to the end.